# Which delimiter should be used configuring multiple urls for ASPNETCORE_URLS in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

I mean there:

[image]

I have tried space , comma, semicolon - each time getting this exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'A path base can only 
be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().'
```

or

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unrecognized scheme in 
server address ' http://localhost:60775/'. Only 'http://' is supported.'
```

Comment: It's a semicolon. What's the full value of `ASPNETCORE_URLS` you're trying to provide when using a semicolon?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Lets create an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a semicolon, but remove all spaces between items, e.g. after semicolon.